# Should I double the size of my database field when allowing an external process to enter data to my database field of the same size?

Tags: database, data-storage

I have a frontend application that allows users to enter an issue containing text data up to 2,000 characters that is stored in a table in my database...(My database table field size is 2,000 characters). The user will assign the issue to a single support analyst and wait for a response. There is an external process that allows the support analyst to send a reply back to the user that also allows 2,000 characters to be entered. I do not have control over the external process and multiple replies can be sent back to the user from the support analyst. Should I double the size of my field that holds the text to 4,000 characters? How should I handle the data that exceeds my field size?

Currently I am truncating any data that exceeds my field size. is that the correct way to handle the process?